# Blazor Server Pagination Component .NET 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, pagination, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been working on a Blazor Server project using .NET 7, and am looking to implement pagination into the listings on my site. Currently my data comes from both APIs and personal databases and is stored in Lists across various components. I would like to break up the large amount of data through a reusable pagination component that can be applied to all of my lists.

Currently I am struggling to find an existing Pagination example/plugin for Blazor Server. Any guides I have found are not working with .NET 7 or are meant for Blazor WASM, and any plugins I have found I cannot figure out how to use correctly.

I have tried following this guide, but it is vague, and I cannot get it to work: https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-pager-component/

I have tried the following plugin, which seems pretty outdated:
https://github.com/villainoustourist/Blazor.Pagination/

Anything else I have found/tried is meant for Blazor WASM or .NET MVC. Could anyone point me in the right direction for creating a pagination component for Blazor Server that's ideal for .NET 7? Or, if there is a convenient plugin that already exists for my use case, that would work too. I do not mind creating my own components, but I am not sure where to start. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my component which I use across all of my apps. CSS is based on Bootstrap 5.2. You might want to change it.

My way to go here is to generate the HTML based on page parameters and use redirection.

```
@if (TotalPages > 1)
{
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
        <ul class="pagination pagination-primary">
           
            @if (CurrentPageNumber > 1)
            {
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="@GetUrl(1)">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }

            @if (StartPage != MaxPage)
            {
                @for (int i = StartPage; i <= MaxPage; i++)
                {
                    string subClass = CurrentPageNumber == i ? "active" : string.Empty;

                    <li class="page-item @subClass"><a class="page-link" href="@GetUrl(i)">@i</a></li>
                }
            }
            
            @if (CurrentPageNumber < TotalPages)
            {
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="@GetUrl(TotalPages)">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </nav>
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string NavUrl { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    [Parameter] public int CurrentPageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    [Parameter] public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; } = 30;
    [Parameter] public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get
        {
            if (TotalItems == 0 || ItemsPerPage == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)TotalItems / (double)ItemsPerPage);
        }
    }

    public int StartPage
    {
        get
        {
            int startPage = CurrentPageNumber - 2;
            if (startPage < 1)
            {
                startPage = 1;
            }

            return startPage;
        }
    }

    public int MaxPage
    {
        get
        {
            int maxPage = StartPage + 4;

            if (maxPage > TotalPages)
            {
                maxPage = TotalPages;
            }

            return maxPage;
        }
    }

    public string GetUrl(int page) => $"{NavUrl}{page}";
}
```

I can implement the pagination then like this:

```
<Pagination TotalItems="YOUR_VARIABLE_WITH_TOTAL_ITEMS_AMOUNT" CurrentPageNumber="YOUR_VARIABLE_FOR_THE_CURRENT_PAGE" NavUrl="YOUR_PAGE/Page/" />
```

The only thing left todo is to specify a second route for my page and call something to fill your two variables with data.

For example:

```
@page "/Customer"
@page "/Customer/Page/{Page:int}"

@code {
    [Parameter] public int Page { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // Do something with your Page here
        Filter.Page = Page;
        await LoadAsync();
    }
    private async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        
        TotalItems = 100; // CALL FUNCTION HERE TO GET THE NUMBER OF TOTAL ITEMS
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this code. My pagination component appears to be working perfect. I assumed that I needed to incorporate my own logic into the example you gave me in order to get the pagination working properly:
`@for (var i = 0; i < ItemsPerPage; i++)
{ itemNumber = ((Page - 1) * ItemsPerPage) + i; <p>Item: @itemNumber</p> }`
Right before the `<Pagination />` component within the example `/Customer` code you provided. Essentially, it looks like I need to use my Page and ItemsPerPage variables to display appropriate loop items.
Is this the correct approach for using these elements?

Comment: Hi you'll need to provide those variables to the component itself. I'Ve put the code on Github and added a clear example to the readme. https://github.com/MarvinKlein1508/Blazor.Pagination

Answer (score 2):

Steve Sanderson recently released a paging component. It was shown during his "What's new for Blazor in .Net 7" presentation and may work for your scenario.

https://aspnet.github.io/quickgridsamples/paging

This is a link to his presentation on the topic:
https://youtu.be/evW4Gj4sHsk?t=415